# How to solve the SSLError of using python to insert data into bigquery table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-colaboratory, sslerrorhandler

I'm maintaining a data pipeline of a youtube channel, and I try to insert the live streaming chat data into my bigquery table.
I was successfully inserted into the same table before, but the error occur when I was using the same code (it's really weird).
I use cloud function as my env, and the code is as follow:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from functions_framework import http

def insert_to_bigquery(table_id, data):
    client = bigquery.Client() 
    dataset_id = 'test_youtube_data'
    
    table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
    table = client.get_table(table_ref)
    # insert into table
    errors = client.insert_rows_json(
        table=table, 
        json_rows=data,
        ignore_unknown_values=True, 
        skip_invalid_rows=True) 
    print(f'Insert response: {errors}')
    if errors:
        print(f'Encountered errors while inserting rows: {errors}')
    else:
        print(f'Successfully inserted {len(data)} rows.')
        print(data[10])

def get_streams_from_channel(channel_id, limit=10): # get data
    ...

def insert_chat_messages_to_bigquery(stream_id, chat_messages):
    rows_to_insert = []

    for message in chat_messages:
        data = {
        "stream_id": stream_id,
        "time_in_seconds": message['time_in_seconds'],
        "action_type": message['action_type'],
        "message": message['message'],
        "emotes_id": message['emotes'][0]['id'] if 'emotes' in message and len(message['emotes']) > 0 else None,
        "emotes_name": message['emotes'][0]['name'] if 'emotes' in message and len(message['emotes']) > 0 else None,
        "emotes_is_custom_emoji": message['emotes'][0]['is_custom_emoji'] if 'emotes' in message and len(message['emotes']) > 0 else None,
        "message_id": message['message_id'],
        "timestamp": message['timestamp'],
        "time_text": message['time_text'],
        "author_name": message['author']['name'],
        "author_images_url": message['author']['images'][0]['url'],
        "author_images_id": message['author']['images'][0]['id'],
        "author_id": message['author']['id'],
        "message_type": message['message_type']
        }
        rows_to_insert.append(data)

    insert_to_bigquery("temp_stream_data", rows_to_insert)  # insert

@http
def store_new_channel_streams(request):
    channel_id = 'UCjv4bfP_67WLuPheS-Z8Ekg'
    limit = 3
    new_streams = get_streams_from_channel(channel_id, limit)
    
    # download the data
    for stream_id in new_streams:
        # url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={stream_id}"
        try:
            print(stream_id)
            chat_messages = get_chat_messages(stream_id)
            insert_chat_messages_to_bigquery(stream_id, chat_messages)
        except VideoNotFound:
            print(f"Video {stream_id} not found, skipping.")
            continue


    return f"Stored {len(new_streams)} new channel streams to BigQuery.", 200
```

and I got SSLError as follow:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bigquery.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bigquery/v2/projects/triple-voyage-377203/datasets/test_youtube_data/tables/stream_data/insertAll?prettyPrint=false (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)')))
```

Log screen shot:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFJyZ.png)

I also ran the same code in google colab, and I get the same error.

I'm pretty sure my data is suit with table schema in bigquery, and the example data is as follow:

```
{'stream_id': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBi1_Ggs39U', 'time_in_seconds': -1837, 'action_type': 'add_chat_item', 'message': ':_MIZUKILazy::_MIZUKILazy::_MIZUKILazy:', 'emotes_id': 'UCjv4bfP_67WLuPheS-Z8Ekg/fd89YfbtJ8_j8wTi2Ki4Ag', 'emotes_name': ':_MIZUKILazy:', 'emotes_is_custom_emoji': True, 'message_id': 'ChwKGkNQdjB1c2FucElBREZiM0R3Z1FkQ0NzQzdn', 'timestamp': 1690097427605763, 'time_text': '-30:37', 'author_name': '倉鼠', 'author_images_url': 'https://yt4.ggpht.com/ytc/AOPolaSpe3eNbZY01DHEOdApwgJOwcIuhGj2VIouEvBaHA', 'author_images_id': 'source', 'author_id': 'UCbpvt7VyEpZwJNfwpf09aFw', 'message_type': 'text_message'}, {'stream_id':...
```

But I still can't see any data in bigquery table.

I really don't know what's wroung here, thanks for reading my question!

Comment: What is the version of openssl that your code is using? Your problem is often caused by using an old version.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, thank you for your comment! I'm currently using "OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022", both in cloud function and colab.

Comment: what is the Python package name and version?

Comment: @JohnHanley, I'm using google-cloud-bigquery version 3.10.0, and I assign functions-framework==3.* in my requirements.txt in cloud function, all of it running under Python 3.10.

Comment: `pip freeze` (use pip3 on Linux systems) will show you the packages. You can also print out a package's version using `.__version__`. There are a number of packages supporting OpenSSL, you must figure out which one you are using.

Comment: @JohnHanley Sorry, I didn't get your meaning, I thought google cloud would solve all of the authentication problems because I had never used OpenSSL-related packages before. What suggestion will you give me about solving this problem using OpenSSL packages?